# It throws an error when I switch to Wordpress Permalink

Tags: php, php-8, ubuntu-22.04, litespeed, openlitespeed

I did a fresh clean install of WordPress. My WordPress site is working but currently the URL structure is in the format `?p=11`.

On the permalinks page I select `example.com/%postname%/`. Currently published pages give a 404 error. When I try to post a new post it gives an error: Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response. On the site health page it throws an error: REST API encountered an unexpected result. Everything I restore the URL is fixed. Why am I having this problem? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS and openlitespeed. My PHP version is 8.1

Comment: Have you enabled rewrite loading from htaccess? https://openlitespeed.org/kb/wordpress/#Add_a_Rewrite_Rule_in_the_vHost_to_Make_Permalinking_Work